# How to manage DynamoDB provisioned capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS and creating an application that will need to put ~10,000 items into a DynamoDB. 
This could happen at random intervals several times a day.

What is the best way to provision write capacity in this scenario?

With a low provisioned write capacity I'd have to throttle the PutItem requests in my application so the overall write time would take several minutes. This is unacceptable to the user.

I don't want to provision a high write capacity if for 90% of the time it won't be needed.

This seems like an option: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scale-dynamodb-with-dynamic-dynamodb/ (Although you can only decrease provisions 4 times a day http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#How_often_can_I_change_my_provisioned_throughput)

This is another option: [Avoid throttle dynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813873/avoid-throttle-dynamodb), but seems overly complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

Would it be possible/sensible to upload the data to S3 as JSON and then have a Lambda function put the items in the database at the required speed?

Are there any other strategies for dealing with this bulk input? Should I be looking at a different database?

Answer (score 1):

One model that works, if you don't need the ability to read back right after you perform a write is to send all your requests to an SQS queue first, and have a background task that takes items from the queue and writes them to DynamoDB at a defined upper rate; this works well to smooth out the spikes during high-write periods. SQS, if you haven't used it yet, is very easy to work with - but this does require an always running instance somewhere to do that work for you.

This also has the benefit that SQS will accept almost any amount of messages as fast as you can submit them, and the cost per message is the same, no matter the velocity of the writes.

Comment: This is an option. 

As a sanity check, is there any reason not to upload the data to S3 and then process with Lambda into DynamoDB?

As an aside, why can SQS "accept almost any amount of messages as fast as you can submit them" What database is it using?